# Is this right to say that Xcode 8.0 Beta work with iOS 10 only(minimum requirement)?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently download the Xcode 8.0 Beta and run my app but it shows me the error, as follows:

> Signing for CocoaLumberjack requires a development team. Select a
>   development team in the Target Editor. Code signing is required for
>   product type 'Framework' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

I search for the solution and I found somewhere that Xcode 8.0 Beta requires 'iOS 10.0' as a minimum requirement.Is this true?

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, Xcode 8 is required for development against iOS 10, but you don't need iOS 10 on your device to use Xcode 8. Your error message seems to indicate you haven't set your development team in your project

Comment: It might be better to say iOS 10 development requires Xcode 8.  Are you more concerned about code signing, developing for iOS 10, both, neither?

Comment: I set both the development team as well as the code signing, as I set in the Xcode-7.1. It is working fine in Xcode 7.1.